# Creating View SQL Server ;With A as

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I am getting the top 1 row after grouping and my query is as follows. This works fine but when I try to create a view out of it I get a syntax error.

```
create view dbo.v_test 
as 
   ;With A as 
      SELECT 
          col1,col2,col3, 
          ROW_NUMBER over (PARTITION by col1, col2, col3 
                           order by col4 desc) as RN  
      from dbo.Test
    )
    select * 
    from A 
    where RN < 1
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near ';'

Comment: Well, that's not how you create a view; that is invalid syntax. The message tells you the problem.

Comment: Also, you need to specify what RDBMS you are using (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) - hard to help you without that info.

Comment: Thanks Ed. SQL Server was specified in the subject line. Harsh helped fix  my error below.

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding. The requirement for a common table expression is that the previous statement end with a semicolon. But people aren't used to ending their statements with semicolons, so they put one *at the front* of the cte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it is SQL server, something like this should work:

```
create view dbo.v_test as
With A as 
(
SELECT col1,col2,col3, ROW_NUMBER() over ( PARTITION by col1,col2,col3 order by col4 desc ) as RN 
from dbo.Test) 
select * from A where RN<1
GO
```